# Compare Images By Color Using a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: image-processing, colors, genetic-algorithm, hsv

I am right now in a serious problem, I need to compare images of flowers (carnations) using a genetic algorithm, the program must determine which variety does the flower belongs to (until now I am using 15 different varieties), the thing is I am having difficulties constructing the chromosome, right know I am only analysing the HSV of each image, then a take every channel and calculate the mean for each (n=255), after that I calculate the correlation between HS, HV and SV, I expected that the mean would be enough to locate any new flower next to the clusters of flowers of the variety it belongs (by the way, I have a database of all the flowers used for training purpose) by calculating the distance between the mean of the flower and the centroids of each cluster, and probably using the correlations for adjustment, but that distance is usually way smaller to a different variety than the one it  must be. Is there a way to classify this flowers using ONLY colours (I've read of applications that uses the texture, but that's way out of my league), especially using a genetic algorithm (I know Neural Networks are more appropriate to this kind of analysis but that's what the teacher asked)?. Thank you very much. By the way I am working on OpenCV, don’t know if it's relevant. PS: Excuse my English if any mistakes were done, not my native language.

Comment: All of this is really confusing. You say "must determine the variety of flower" which sounds like a supervised learning  (classification) problem. But then talk about clusters and clustering (which is unsupervised learning). I guess the main problem with your question/approach is that genetic algorithms is an optimization method, you still need to say what function you're trying to optimize (is it a classification objective function? which one? is it a clustering objective function? which one?)

Comment: Well to tell you the truth this is my first attempt at a genetic algorithm, so I think that this is supervised learning, as I need to classify flowers, thought the objetive function is of classification. I thougt of cluster to encapsulate the different varietes and then find closest one accoding to the flowers used for testing, Don't know if this help to clarify my answer. Thanks anyway.